# Add a success flash message in symfony controller and show it in Sonata Admin?

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, flash-message

I want to add a flash message in symfony controller (DefaultController) and show it in Sonata (Entity)Admin Class as regular flash message.

```
$this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Welcome to the Death Star, have a magical day!');
```

Or

```
$this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('sonata_flash_success', 'Welcome to the Death Star, have a magical day!');
```

In my symfony controller the FlashBag has all the flash messages in queue:

```
Session {#95
  #storage: NativeSessionStorage {#94
    #bags: array:2 [
      "attributes" => AttributeBag {#90
        -name: "attributes"
        -storageKey: "_sf2_attributes"
        #attributes: & []
      }
      "flashes" => FlashBag {#89
        -name: "flashes"
        -flashes: & array:1 [
          "success" => array:3 [
            0 => "Welcome to the Death Star, have a magical day!!"
            1 => "Welcome to the Death Star, have a magical day!!"
            2 => "Welcome to the Death Star, have a magical day!!"
          ]
        ]
        -storageKey: "_sf2_flashes"
      }
    ]
    #started: true
    #closed: false
    #saveHandler: SessionHandlerProxy {#91
      #handler: NativeFileSessionHandler {#93}
      #wrapper: true
      #active: true
      #saveHandlerName: "files"
    }
    #metadataBag: MetadataBag {#92
      -name: "__metadata"
      -storageKey: "_sf2_meta"
      #meta: & array:3 [
        "u" => 1500032412
        "c" => 1500019957
        "l" => "0"
      ]
      -lastUsed: 1500032408
    }
  }
  -flashName: "flashes"
  -attributeName: "attributes"
}
```

Session dump in Sonata (Entity)Admin Class:

```
Session {#95 ▼
  #storage: NativeSessionStorage {#94 ▼
    #bags: array:2 [▼
      "attributes" => AttributeBag {#90 ▼
        -name: "attributes"
        -storageKey: "_sf2_attributes"
        #attributes: & array:1 [▶]
      }
      "flashes" => FlashBag {#89 ▼
        -name: "flashes"
        -flashes: & []
        -storageKey: "_sf2_flashes"
      }
    ]
    #started: true
    #closed: false
    #saveHandler: SessionHandlerProxy {#91 ▶}
    #metadataBag: MetadataBag {#92 ▶}
  }
  -flashName: "flashes"
  -attributeName: "attributes"
}
```

But in Sonata admin neither the flash message is shown, nor the flash bag is emptied.

Comment: Do you have modified the `standard_layout.html.twig`? by default, this one have a `notice` block with `{% include 'SonataCoreBundle:FlashMessage:render.html.twig' %}` that should show all flash messages.

Comment: @yceruto The notice block is there, but for some reason the Symfony flash messages are not rendering. 
Standard_layout -->
{% block notice %}{% include 'SonataCoreBundle:FlashMessage:render.html.twig' %}{% endblock notice %}
...
P.s. Sonata's own flash messages are working fine.

Comment: `[P.s. Sonata's own flash messages are working fine.]` Then by using `sonata_flash_success` does work?

Comment: more details about this topic here https://sonata-project.org/bundles/core/master/doc/reference/flash_messages.html

Comment: No even the sonata_flash_error/success are shown. I had already exhausted all the usual culprits. The flash message is put in FlashBag but are not shown in Sonata Admin.